# React with Babel without Node

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a React application without having to use npm or yarn, just want it to work by opening page.html file.

I have this code in both files, cockpit.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cockpit-project/cockpit/master/src/base1/cockpit.css" type="text/plain" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cockpit-project/cockpit/master/src/base1/cockpit.js" type="text/plain"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" type="text/plain" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" type="text/plain" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js" type="text/jsx"></script>   
    <title>Cockpit Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="root"></div>



    <script type="text/babel" src="cockpitTest.jsx"></script>

      </body>

      </html>
```

and cockpitTest.jsx:

```
"use strict";


const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')

    class CockpitTest extends React.Component { 

    componentDidMount() {
      console.log("asd")
    }

    render() { 
        return (
        <div>
          <h1>test</h1>
        </div>

      );
      } 
    }

    function App(){
      return(
      <div>
        <CockpitTest name="Test"/>
      </div>
      )
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('rootElement'))
```

but still I'm getting a blank screen when h1 text is expected. Console doesn't say anything either, it's just blank. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have **lots** of problems

## Content-Type

You've set `type` attributes on all your script and link elements to tell the browser that the CSS and scripts are in formats it doesn't understand. **Don't do that.**

Only the JSX file itself (in your *last* `<script>`) should have a `type` attribute.

## Github is not a hosting service

You are trying to host the cockpit files on `raw.github.com`. This is not designed to be used as a CDN and returns data with the wrong `Content-Type` header. Use a real hosting service.

## URL

You named the file *cockpit.jsx*  but said `src="cockpitTest.jsx"`

## Missing element

You said `document.getElementById('rootElement')` but also `id="root"`. These do not match.

---

## You are working without Node.js

The developer tools for React use Node.js to compile it for production-level performance. There's very little reason to not use them all the way through the development process.

Comment: When I do remove type attributes, I get errors in the console as this one for every script:  from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: @Karl — Then, in addition to all the problems in the code that this answer addresses, you failed to load the HTML document from an HTTP server.

Comment: I did fix all of the problems on the above, and I just copied both cockpit.js and .css files from github and added them to my local folder of the react project. And I still get the same error mentioned above + (babel.min.js:24 GET file:///A:/Users/Karl/Documents/GitHub/Cockpit-test/cockpitTest.jsx net::ERR_FAILED) this one. Do you have any suggestions how I might get this to work?

Comment: The same as my previous comment: **use an HTTP server**

Answer (score 0):

1. First make it a javascript file .js

Then you can either:
Change:
`rootElement = document.querySelector('#root'));`
AND:
`ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement)`

OR:
`ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'))`
AND:
Delete your constant.

I even got React Router to work, but had problems when it came to separating components out into files for a tidy structure. Couldn't get imports to work inside app.js. Seems like Babel should have helped with imports and exports, but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly - on your script type your using type "application/babel". This is not a valid media type, you probably want to use "application/javascript". This could be why nothing is displayed.

Secondly - the script you're using is not valid JS, you're using JSX which browsers cannot understand. JSX is what allows us to write html-like tags in JavaScript (the < /> for example). You would either have to write JS instead of JSX, or transpile your JSX using a transpiler such as babel. I would suggest running a compiler such as babel.

Read more about JSX [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html).

Comment: "Firstly - on your script type your using type "application/babel". This is not a valid media type" — Yes, it is. It is used to identify scripts that need to be interpreted with the Babel library that is loaded just before the title element.

Comment: "I would suggest running a compiler such as babel." — They are!!